# Invalid length - Digital Signature - Convert From Base64

Tags: c#, wcf, hash, digital-signature

I am implementing a digital signature and its verification between two of my applications. I am using C#/WCF to do this (sender). I use the below code to generate the signature.

```
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptingkey.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1")));
```

The below code is used in my second application (receiver) to generate the byte array for validation.

```
byte[] signatureByte = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
```

This works fine when I have both the applications running on my local machine. However, when I deploy the second application to the server, I get the below error where I have the above statement Convert.FromBase64String(signature):

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

I have the same certificate installed on my server and in my localmachine.

The sending application is a WCF service, and the receiving application is an ASP.NET MVC web application. I am posting the signature and some additional information to one of its controllers.

Comment: could you post the complete signature string?

Comment: the one you're receiving in the WCF Service end